# PHP SimpleXML obtaining data

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a response in the following format

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:ns='urn:xtk:myQyery' xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ExecuteQueryResponse xmlns='urn:xtk:myQyery' SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>
        <pOutput xsi:type='ns:Element' SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle='http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap/literalxml'>
            <recipient email="myemail@email.com"/>
        </pOutput>
    </ExecuteQueryResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So first thing I do is load the string

```
public function checkResponse($serverResponse) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($serverResponse);

    if($xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->Fault) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The first thing I do is look for a fault, and if there is one, return false.  If everything is ok, I need to return the email address from the xml.  I have tried the following without success

```
return $xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->ExecuteQueryResponse->pOutput->recipient;
```

How would I go about getting the email address?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

email is an attribute of the 'recipient' node.

You can try this:

```
return $xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->ExecuteQueryResponse->pOutput->recipient->attributes()->email
```

http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes

Comment: If I do that I get both Trying to get property of non-object and Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry.
That's because de namescpaces. Try this:

$xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children()->ExecuteQueryResponse->pOutput->recipient->attributes()->email

http://www.sitepoint.com/simplexml-and-namespaces/